# The difference between React HOC and render-props pattern?

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I have just learned these two patterns. I'm quite confused about how to use these pattern correctly.

I created a component and try to apply these patterns. Everything works the same.

Source code: https://codesandbox.io/s/n504v2njr4

### Render Props pattern

```
class Toggle extends Component {
  state = {
    on: false,
  }

  onToggle = () => {
    this.setState(({ on }) => ({ on: !on}));
  }

  getStateHelper = () => ({
    on: this.state.on,
    toggle: this.onToggle,
  });

  render() {
    return this.props.children(this.getStateHelper())
  }
}
```

**Usage**

```
  <Toggle>
    {({on, toggle}) => (<button onClick={toggle}>{on ? 'On' : 'Off'}</button>)}
  </Toggle>
```

### High Order Component pattern

```
function ToggleHoc(Comp) {
  return class ToggleHocWrap extends Component {
    state = {
      on: false,
    }

    onToggle = () => {
      this.setState(({ on }) => ({ on: !on}));
    }

    getStateHelper = () => ({
      on: this.state.on,
      toggle: this.onToggle,
    });

    render() {
      return (<Comp {...this.getStateHelper()} />)
    }
  }
}
```

**Usage**

```
function TestToggle({ on, toggle }) {
  return (<button onClick={toggle}>{on ? 'On' : 'Off'}</button>)
}

const WithToggle = ToggleHoc(TestToggle);
```

Please help me!. Thank you, guys.

Comment: https://cdb.reacttraining.com/use-a-render-prop-50de598f11ce

Comment: I think I should post as a answer so maybe others can refer the same link

Answer (score -3):

Actually, there are some issues with Mixin as well as HOC, like ghost state and props,  Whoever use multiple Mixin and HOC in one component they always need to figure it out who is setting and passing the props and state,
- Name collision is one more know issue.
- Both Mixin and HOC use Static composition.

While render props don't have an above-mentioned issue as it uses the dynamic composition so there is no name collision.

for more info please check below mentioned link.

[Check Here](https://cdb.reacttraining.com/use-a-render-prop-50de598f11ce)

Comment: Please avoid link only answer https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/8231/are-answers-that-just-contain-links-elsewhere-really-good-answers